# Vegalite axis format

Tags: formatting, vega

is it possible to dynamically change format of the axis in group bar chart? I am developing bar chart either price (metrics) bar chart or volume bar chart ( metrics). how to change the format of the axis. How to achieve in vega lite. I have tried many options but could not find any way to switch the formatting. In attached code, would like to set "$"format if formatType = dollar

[code](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgAcABh1L4NMljQAmPUrVJMKVKGJJBDOBDQBtUDgBOcAPoBGczR9EG8-AE4dYKUw3wA2KNQQnDYITHjE-wtQ1PTItH8xZNyAoNRzEMwATxw4NBAAWSRZMjZFECg2BllMesw4eSUAMzYvZEwAFRq69DU2QUEkLxAAXwVPH1LE5M38pJjNhOictIy0SJiSvf8AFmLTwMyLkGra+oBBHBxBOqVO7t66EwygG1XaIzG1imb1m80WyxWAF01i8vM0IBCEO5QCNBGp3KFNo92rF8gc-EdLqdKSc8lEqelicjEUpFlU4MtUB4QMgvABrerCWS-EADTpqGgtNCgAAe0pAQxocDx9T5cCq7RkXkBbkJfmJ5N8ZL1ZwZptpRvpFqZKI1dgVSpV6AcThFrxmIAAjgxmpg6NYaKR2kgZTQIP55ZjrPKAKIy7z1KOYAAUVkwDAQlBdzgUAHIwApKDpTBBcwBKVYokNh+WLJjKuPeCPoJOp6wZrOOHP5wvF0sV1lIeuCRuckBpjNuXNJ6FwXOIgC8C9zcwWS1zAH5WxPM9m4HmC0WS+XUNv27uu-vc0f+5W-vNRpHHfigdN2u76rI2AhJY52j8yAGF9QDrBt4zHHdO1dAACABqXNoP4aCENg6DIP+HpKxWJEViAA)

Comment: Where is your spec? It is not clear what you want to do at the moment.

Comment: added more details about the issue and configuration is also shared